# Is there a way to display custom discord stuff on a website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, discord, embed

I've recently started learning front-end web development (html, css, js) and as a learning project I started making a website for our friends group discord server using **React**. I wanted to have 3 things from our server.

1. I wanted to display the user with most minutes spent in a voice channel on the server
2. I wanted to display the user with most messages sent in any channel on the server
3. I wanted to display all online members with a particular role from the server

How would I go about this? Could it be done?

I've lightly touched what APIs are and am not really sure how I would implement something like this. I've tried looking at Discords developer documentation and its rather overwhelming.

Youtube and Google weren't much help or maybe I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

Also their own discord widget could maybe replace what I want with number 3, is the widget maybe customizable?

Any help, especially in a 'explain it to me like I'm 5' manner, is much appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific statistics you need, there aren’t actually endpoints that provide this info! It *is* possible to get all the info you need, but it’ll be a long process to get it.

1:
I don’t believe discord keeps logs of how much time a user has spent in a voice channel. To monitor this, you would probably need to set up a bot and have it constantly run.

2: Again, there isn’t an API endpoint that monitors this. You could fetch messages individually from each channel, but this is very API intensive (and will probably get stopped by a rate limit of some sort).

3: Hooray! Finally something we can use! Using the HTTP endpoint [List Guild Members](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members) which contains an array of people in your server. Each member has a roles object, which you can interate through to get the role. You’ll need to register an application at https://discord.com/developers/applications and follow the [Getting Started docs tutorial](https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started#step-1-creating-an-app) to get ready for using the API. Best of luck!